# Seeing what locks are held in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, locking, deadlock

I'm trying to debug a multi-threaded application that works as it should, except it semi-randomly ceases to do anything and then hangs indefinitely. Pausing and checking the call stack reveals nothing, as it just shows external code (on the GUI thread).

It definitely smells like deadlock to me, but I can't even begin to figure out what the cause is.

I'm trying to use the built in performance tools in Visual Studio, however I haven't found any data that is useful to me. I've tried both the Concurrency Visualizer and the Resource Contention tool. After the program hangs, these tools both show no activity on any thread besides the normal baseline of the GUI thread. I can't find a way to see what locks, if any, the threads are waiting on.

What would really be useful is for a given point in time, being able to see what threads were holding which locks, what threads were waiting on what locks, and where in the code these calls came from.

Is there a way to do this in either Visual Studio or, if not, is there another tool which might help?